# How to query/set the character encoding?

Tags: character-encoding

How can I find out what character encoding Emacs employs in saving a text file to disk? And how can I specify this encoding?

---

Operating system: macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.5
Emacs: GNU Emacs 25.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From chapter "[Choosing Coding Systems for Output](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Output-Coding.html#Output-Coding)" of emacs manual:

> Once Emacs has chosen a coding system for a buffer, it stores that
>   coding system in ‘buffer-file-coding-system’.  That makes it the default
>   for operations that write from this buffer into a file, such as
>   ‘save-buffer’ and ‘write-region’.  You can specify a different coding
>   system for further file output from the buffer using
>   ‘set-buffer-file-coding-system’

So the encoding is stored in variable `buffer-file-coding-system` (whose value you can examine with `C-h v`) and the function `set-buffer-file-coding-system` can be used to change it.  However the function's docstring includes:

> If you know exactly what coding system you want to use,
>   just set the variable ‘buffer-file-coding-system’ directly.

So the advantage in using `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system` is that you can get completion for possible coding systems, with the `TAB` key.

Also note that you can get information on a coding system with `M-x describe-coding-system` (bound to `C-h C`).

Comment: Thanks. Examining the value of the variable `buffer-file-coding-system` with `C-h v` for the file `test.tex` yields: "Its value is ‘undecided-unix’
Local in buffer test.tex; global value is utf-8-unix". What does it mean?

Comment: Also, what are the possible values that can be assigned to `buffer-file-coding-system`? Is there a list of possible values?

Comment: Using `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system` you can get completion for possible values, through the TAB key.  You can get info on a coding system with `C-h C`.